# How to write and call wrapper without decorator in python

Tags: python

I'd like to write wrapper function for various functions.

How can I write the wrapper function and call it?

- Without decorator

This is my expectation but doesn't work.

```
import external_library # example

def wrapper(func):
    return func()

def test1(a,b):
    print(a,b)

def test2(a,b,c,d):
    print(a,b,c,d)

wrapper(test1(1,2)) # a,b
wrapper(test2(1,2,3,4)) # 1,2,3,4
wrapper(external_library.some_api()) # working like direct call
```

I got an error

```
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior? Something else?

Comment: I got error on wrapper method : 'OOOO object is not callable'

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) and you'll find that you should `from retry import retry` instead.

Comment: I've simplified the question because it seems confusing.

Comment: Now it's a different error/question.  You might want to take a moment to debug your new error before posting here.

Comment: `wrapper(test)` would be valid, because `test` is callable, but `test()` means you are instead executing test and passing the return value of the function to `wrapper`. 
This feels like it may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and why is using a decorator to wrap your function not an acceptable solution?

Comment: I'd like to wrap external library method. I can't modify the library method definition. So I can't put a decorator on it.

Comment: A library method (as in, a method on a class in a library), or a library function?

Comment: methods on a class in a library.

Answer (score 1):

`wrapper()` takes a function as an argument. Just add some `lambda` keywords and it should work:

```py
one = wrapper(lambda: some_api.request_one(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap methods of a class you are importing from a library, you will need to instead write a new class inheriting from the library class.  Then you will only need to write overrides for the methods you want to wrap, where you just add your wrapper code, and then call `super().method()`

So lets say you want to override method `test` on class `Foo` from library `bar` to print the time to execute, you could do the following

```
import time
from bar import Foo

class Baz(Foo):
    def test(self, x):
        start = time.time()
        super().test(x)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Foo.test() time to execute : {end - start}")

A = Baz()

A.test(5)
# Output: Foo.test() time to execute : 0.135
```

In all other ways, an instance of Baz will act as an instance of Foo